# How to link to individual Magento multi store with SID

Tags: magento, session

I have two stores set up with magento 1.7.2 using sub domains:

store #1:
www.store.com

store #2:
alt.store.com

Within the footer there is a call to the store selector however the output is in the form of a drop down menu. I've searched for hours and can't find a solution for what I'm trying to do which is to have the ability to link either text and/or an image so that switching between store is more user friendly. Something similar to how users switch between stores on gap.com

If I link directly to the store's URL without the SID (which is what the drop down introduces the first time you switch between stores) then items in the cart are not remembered. This seems like something that should be a lot easier than it has been trying to find an answer ... Any ideas on how to make this work?

When on website #1, you'd see a link like [click here to shop on our other store](http://alt.store.com/?SID=863858476385)

And then on website #2 if you want to go back to store #1, I'm assuming the SID won't be needed since you're already cookied but in case you aren't the logic should include the SID ... At least that's what I understand from seeing the drop down in action and the bits of info I read about. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Within a block class you can use $this->getUrl(). Investigate Mage_Core_Model_Url. You should be able to do something like: $this->getUrl('...', array('_store' => ...))

Answer (score 0):

Magento has its own stores switcher block. You can use it for your case.
If you look at page.xml layout of base template, you will see something like this:

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Footer</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
</block>
```

So, if you want to show store switcher in footer, you should edit file `page/html/footer.phtml` and add bellow code in place you want to show:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher'); ?>
```

If you want to change dropdown to links, you should edit template `page/switch/stores.phtml` like bellow:

```
<?php if(count($this->getGroups())>1): ?>
<div class="store-switcher">
    <label for="select-store"><?php echo $this->__('Select Store:') ?></label>
    <ul id="select-store">
        <?php foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group): ?>
            <?php $_selected = ($_group->getId()==$this->getCurrentGroupId()) ? 'active' : '' ?>
            <li class="store-<?php echo $_group->getCode()?> <?php echo $_selected ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_group->getHomeUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_group->getName()) ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**NOTE: Maybe you need flush cache after edit anything in footer because Magento cache footer block by default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer however as I mentioned in my original post, the answer you provided gives me a drop down. Instead, I'm looking for how to link an image or text and not the traditional drop down as you described.